# three level hibernate query join one to many relationship

Tags: hql, one-to-many

I have 3 tables

```
table 1
country
countryid countryname
```

this table has a one to many join to table 2 that is state

```
 table 2
 state
 stateid statename countryid
```

table 2 has a one to many join to city table

```
table 3
city
cityid cityname stateid
```

i tried to read country using query

```
 session.createQuery("from Country c where c.countryName=:countryname order by c.countryName");
```

it gives me country object but the list of states are empty??
what am i doing wrong???

Answer (score 0):

ok i fixed it.
by using cascade.all in @oneToMany annotation

and changed the hql to criteria query.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Country.class, "country");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("country.countryName", countryname));
```

Comment: also dont forget fetch as eager. else the associated list will be blank.